# Examine the series for convergence depending on $\alpha$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

$\{a_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}, \: a_1=\alpha$

$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{8a^2_n-24a_n+24}{a^2_n-2a_n+4}$

This is the first problem with a parameter I am facing. So far I have a guess about the possible limit, that it is $8$. I don't know which criteria for convergence to use.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: That's not a series, it's a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there exists $\,\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=l\in\mathbb R\,,\,$ then

$l=\dfrac{8l^2-24l+24}{l^2-2l+4}\;\;,$

$l^3-2l^2+4l=8l^2-24l+24\;\;,$

$l^3-10l^2+28l-24=0\;\;,$

$(l-2)\left(l^2-8l+12\right)=0\;\;,$

$(l-2)^2(l-6)=0\;\;,$

$l=2\quad\lor\quad l=6\;.$

---

If $\;\alpha<0\,,\,$ then $\;6\!<\!a_{n+1}\!<\!a_n\;$ for all $\;n\geqslant2\,,\;$ hence ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf_\limits{n\geqslant2}\big\{a_n\big\}=l\geqslant6\;\;,\;\;$ consequently ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=6\;.$

If $\;0\!\leqslant\!\alpha\!<\!\dfrac43\,,\,$ then $\;a_n\!\leqslant\!a_{n+1}\!\leqslant6\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb N\,,\,$ hence ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup_\limits{n\in\mathbb N}\big\{a_n\big\}=l\in\big]2,6\big]\;\;,\;\;$ consequently ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=6\;.$

If $\,\dfrac43\!\leqslant\alpha\leqslant2\,,\,$ then $\;a_n\!\leqslant \!a_{n+1}\!\leqslant2\;$ for all $\,n\in\mathbb N\,,\,$ hence ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup_\limits{n\in\mathbb N}\big\{a_n\big\}=l\leqslant2\;\;,\;\;$ consequently ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=2\;.$

If $\;2<\alpha\leqslant6\,,\,$ then $\;a_n\!\leqslant\!a_{n+1}\!\leqslant6\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb N\,,\,$ hence ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=\sup_\limits{n\in\mathbb N}\big\{a_n\big\}=l\in\big]2,6\big]\;\;,\;\;$ consequently ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=6\;.$

If $\;\alpha>6\,,\,$ then $\;6\!<\!a_{n+1}\!<\!a_n\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb N\,,\;$ hence ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf_\limits{n\in\mathbb N}\big\{a_n\big\}=l\geqslant6\;\;,\;\;$ consequently ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=6\;.$

Therefore ,

$\exists\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=\begin{cases}2\quad\text{ if }\;\dfrac43\!\leqslant\alpha\leqslant2\\6\quad\text{ if }\;\alpha\!<\!\dfrac43\;\lor\;\alpha>2\end{cases}\quad.$

Comment: $a_1=0\implies a_2=6$ so first paragraph has an issue.

Comment: @zwim, are there other issues?

Comment: @Angelo where did the $\frac{4}{3}$ come from?

Comment: @Boyan, if you solve the inequality $$a_{n+1}=\frac{8a^2_n-24a_n+24}{a^2_n-2a_n+4}\leqslant2$$ you get $\,\dfrac43\leqslant a_n\leqslant2\;.$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Graph the function $f(x)=\dfrac{8x^2-24x+24}{x^2-2x+4}$ and the line $y=x$, so you can visualize convergence.

Search fore fixed points of $f$, i.e. $f(x)=x$ because if $a_n$ converge, it can only converge to one of the fixed points.

You can identify $4$ regions of interest.

- $a_1>6$ then $a_n$ decreases to $6$
- $2<a_1<6$ then $a_n$ increases to $6$
- $a_1<b$ where $f(b)=2$ on the left, then $a_2>2$ and we are in the precedent cases
- $b<a_1<2$ then $a_n$ increases to $2$

In all cases it seems we have "staircase convergence" (compared to staircase divergence or spiral convergence or cycling indefinitely).

Now to prove it more thoroughly, study $f(x)-x$, it factors well. Remember $a_{n+1}-a_n=f(a_n)-a_n$ so you can determine if the sequence increases or decreases.

In the same way, study $f(x)-2$ and $f(x)-6$ to show the sequence stay the same side of the limit.

Comment: A detail, the sequence begins with $a_1$

Comment: corrected thanks.